# How to QuerySet for Post per month

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a model as such

```
class Post(models.Model):
   submission_time = models.DateTimeField()
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

and I would like to have a queryset where it returns the number of Posts a user has made per month.

I have tried using ExtractMonth as so :

```
user.post_set.annotate(month_sub=ExtractMonth('submission_time')).values('month_sub').annotate(count=Count('month_sub'))
```

But its giving me a QuerySet like this :

```
<QuerySet [{'month_sub': 5, 'count': 1}, {'month_sub': 6, 'count': 1}, {'month_sub': 6, 'count': 1}, {'month_sub': 6, 'count': 1}, {'month_sub': 6, 'count': 1}, {'month_sub': 6, 'count': 1}, {'month_sub': 6, 'count': 1}]>
```

Instead of one like this(Which i'd like to have) :

```
<QuerySet [{'month_sub': 5, 'count': 1}, {'month_sub': 6, 'count': 7}]>
```

Any Ideas on how to receive a queryset like so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quite close, the only thing you are missing is an `.order_by('month_sub')` (yeah, I know that sounds a bit *strange*). So you should write:

```
user.post_set.annotate(
    month_sub=ExtractMonth('submission_time')
).values('month_sub').annotate(
    count=Count('month_sub')
).order_by('month_sub')
```

This will result in query that looks like:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM `post`.`submission_time`) AS `month_sub`,
       COUNT(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM `post`.`submission_time`)) AS `count`
FROM `post`
WHERE `post`.`user_id` = 123
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM `post`.`submission_time`)
ORDER BY `month_sub` ASC
```

(where `123` should be replaced with the `id` of the `user`).

You can perhaps boost performance a *tiny* bit, by using `Count('id')`, although it is possible this has no (noticeable) impact:

```
user.post_set.annotate(
    month_sub=ExtractMonth('submission_time')
).values('month_sub').annotate(
    count=Count('id')
).order_by('month_sub')
```

If I run this on a sample database, I get:

```
<QuerySet [{'count': 273, 'month_sub': 1},
           {'count': 172, 'month_sub': 2},
           {'count': 565, 'month_sub': 3},
           {'count': 59, 'month_sub': 4},
           {'count': 452, 'month_sub': 5},
           {'count': 550, 'month_sub': 6},
           {'count': 622 'month_sub': 7},
           {'count': 43, 'month_sub': 8},
           {'count': 357, 'month_sub': 9},
           {'count': 378, 'month_sub': 10},
           {'count': 868, 'month_sub': 11},
           {'count': 293, 'month_sub': 12}]>
```

(did some formatting to make it easier to inspect the result)